# Is there a smaller tautogram checker?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

I got into code-golfing recently and tried to write the smallest tautogram checker.

A *tautogram* is a sentence in which all words start with the same letter, for example: **Flowers flourish from France**.

Given a sentence as input, determine whether it is a tautogram.

### Test Cases

```
Flowers flourish from France
    True

This is not a Tautogram
    False
```

I came up with this python code (because it is my main language):

```
print(True if len(list(set([x.upper()[0] for x in __import__('sys').argv[1:]]))) == 1 else False)
```

Usage:

```
python3 tautogram.py Flowers flourish from France
# True
python3 tautogram.py This is not a Tautogram
# False
```

The sentence may contain commas and periods, but no other special characters, only upper and lower case letters and spaces.

Its size is 98 bytes. Is there a smaller solution in any language?

Comment: Is it intended as a [`tips`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question limited to [`Python`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)? If so, these both tags should be added.

Comment: Heya friend! This site is usually reserved for explicitly defined problems. Things like "can the input contain punctuation" should be answered before posting, but other than that this is a great first question comparatively to the other new-user questions we usually see. Judging by your examples I'd just clarify that the only characters in the input will be "[A-Za-z ]" and your question will be purely objective. I'd scope out some other questions around here, else this may honestly be a better fit on overflow.

Comment: What do you mean by punctuation? Which characters are included?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Sometimes when you ask for a short solution in stackOverflow the refer to this site :)

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Commas and periods, since others are special characters

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! A few more test cases (including punctuation) would be a great addition to this challenge.

Comment: Btw, in your code, you can take out the if, printing the boolean works

Comment: Need the 2 outputs be consistent or will any truthy/falsey values suffice?

Comment: Some potential extra test cases, to clarify: `Flowers flourish, from France`, `Flowers flourish ,from France`, `Flowers flourish from France.`, `Flowers flourish from France .`, `.Flowers flourish from France`, `Flo.wers flourish fr,om France`

Comment: With no definition of a sentence structure this is unclear. Is ", ," a valid input? Is ",This tolerable" or " This tolerable"? What about "This , ,tolerable, "? ...and what should they output?

Comment: I'm surprised so many regulars answered rather than seeking clarity!

Comment: @JonathanAllan, it was pretty clear to me when originally posted that we should split on spaces and then check if the first character of every string was the same.

Comment: @Shaggy only because you made assumptions (I agree they were most likely correct, but as it stands they may not be).

Comment: @JonathanAllan I answered based on the logical definition of "given a sentence." `This , ,tolerable, ` isn't a sentence, for example.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork "may contain" does not specify this and could allow perfectly normal (English?) sentences to be edited to less normal ones. Regardless, this is not a fruitful discussion; I already said "most likely correct", but I cannot make it so; that is the OPs prerogative.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
l#€нË
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/R/lR05oLew93///vllhcopCWWFSSmZcOpEsyUouKAQ)

---

```
l      # Lowercase input.
 #     # Split on spaces.
  €н   # a[0] of each.
    Ë  # All equal?
```

Did this on mobile excuse the no explanation.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda s:len(set(zip(*s.lower().split())[0]))<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pco7DsIwDADQvafwVpuhQh0RrD1BN2AwkJBIaRLZrhBcPnwGpDe@@rRQ8tj84dQSL5cbg@6Sy6jO8BUrbnRI5eEEadCaoiHRcXsm2o@tSswGHvvpNxR8KqtEDeClLDAJ56vrCbruP@cQFT5yMWCYebVyF16@qb0B)

Came up with this on mobile. Can probably be golfed more.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>57</s> <s>50</s> 41 bytes

```powershell
(-split$args|% s*g 0 1|sort -u).count-eq1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctRCoAgDADQq@yjsAKjLuE9RLSE1WxT@vHuC3r/r9AbWc6IqDpZKZjr4PmQPoIsB2ywdyGuYNu8Bmp3tfHZVdU4/CckpMZZTkhMFzj2d4jmAw)

Takes input and `split`s it on whitespace. Loops through each word, and grabs the first letter by taking the `s`ubstrin`g` starting at position `0` and going for `1` character. Then `sort`s the letters (case-insensitive by default) with the `-u`nique flag to pull out only one copy of each letter, and verifies the `count` of those names are `-eq`ual to `1`. Output is implicit.

*-9 bytes thanks to mazzy.*

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##HctRCoAgDADQq@yjsAKjLuE9RLSE1WxT@vHuC3r/r9AbWc6IqDpZKZjr4PmQPoIsB2ywdyGuYNu8Bmp3tfHZVdU4/CckpMZZTkhMFzj2d4jmAw "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: [35 bytes with regexp](https://tio.run/##fY7BCoJAFEX3fsVLppwRFdoGUSu/QHAjxWDPFEbHZkYKzG@fJsuWPd7qcO7l9vKOStcohCUV7GG0PuHqqv24k6blpqyDU5GHNGFJWOT0sCq2LLCT5x2pB@4iGqRi7oBKyEE1uoZKyRZSxbsSgwiIUQOyRc7qRoN71w4cMj4YeVW8fXsVF9qJDJ6whnEOEO04PnosDV7cOnL@YIV6EMaBjRtN9Ax9Qr88xtsvxHaL7XuTtf/HvgA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy [fixed](https://tio.run/##XY/LCsIwEEX3/YqxRJNIFdwKta78gkI3RQl1@oC0qUmKgvrtMdYH6DCrw5mZO706ozY1SulICTFcXUiErky46JRthS1qumfJJs/mnC35cp5nLInzM2fJJF9x6u5BsGUB@IoYhZ0c10Ep1aAbU0cApVYt7LToCqQREKsH5B8/rRsDvv0pEJCKwapKi/bplUIaL3K4wRSu4wAxnuOlx8Li0UclhxfWaAZpPZj5D4gZYUjYmy/w9B3i648dBnfn6H/cn7AP) trying to understand the intention

Comment: @mazzy I'll let you post the regex version when the question is reopened. It's different enough to warrant its own answer.

Comment: I'm agree. but this question is put on hold, so I can't create a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 80 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBCsMwDETRqwh3EQXa3KDbXCJkYYzcuCi2kGxKTu@m6aw@vAlc3k2po2jKlTNgx5gXW7EZwbCEv09WT3@tI3oRPuCJuxeISa1exeVD@gjeCE04VTC4OXDjb93NFxtELk2TbXeIWnaY1edA0/nqXw). TIO doesn't support Clojure's standard String library though, so the first version will throw a "Can't find lower-case" error.

```clj
(fn[s](use '[clojure.string])(apply =(map first(map lower-case(split s #" ")))))
```

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn tautogram? [s]
  (use '[clojure.string])
  (->> (split s #" ") ; Get words
       (map lower-case)
       (map first) ; Get first letter of each word
       (apply =))) ; And make sure they're all the same
```

I made a version that avoids the import:

```clj
(fn [s](apply =(map #(if(<(-(int %)32)65)(int %)(-(int %) 32))(map first(take-nth 2(partition-by #(= %\ )s))))))

 ; -----

(defn tautogram? [s]
  (->> s
       (partition-by #(= % \ )) ; Split into words
       (take-nth 2) ; Remove spaces
       (map first) ; Get first letter
       ; Convert to uppercased letter code
       (map #(if (< (- (int %) 32) 65) ; If attempting to uppercase puts the letter out of range,
               (int %) ; Go with the current code
               (- (int %) 32))) ; Else go with the uppercased  code
       (apply =))) ; And check if they're all equal
```

But it's **112 Bytes**.

Comment: Here's my Racket solution:
`(define(f s)(apply char=?(map(λ(x)(char-upcase(car(string->list x))))(string-split s))))`

Comment: Much shorter in PicoLisp: `(de f(s)(apply =(mapcar car(split(chop(lowc s))" "))))`

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 71 bytes

```hs
f s|c<-fromEnum.head<$>words s=all(`elem`[-32,0,32]).zipWith(-)c$tail c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBda8IwGIXv@ysORViCrQy9E@vYmAVhsIsJu3CCoaY2LE1KklI2/O9d0orIXnKRc/K8X6mY/eZS9n0JeylWaWl0vVFtPas4O60m606bk4XNmJTkyCWvj/t0MU8ek8X8QGe/ovkUriIpLSaOCYmidz8Nx45bhwzkwxmhzgletJY0ipy3LZZL7ANwuOoM@wjXIHEudceNRSl1a4StECZCbpgqeJxgZ1pOkzt@VwkLf5R2YNix1umzYbVHcyYtpwN6iCJb6e4h9B5mS9cYZ7v6RKgmgW4d9eP4O6ZTxF8q5Ho0DjKAIGV4pbf@twg8nrI71BcbXTJ4DbN20DQesruKGz66FwxVkWVDki8SbH6K/7e5QDuf1gnLg/Rg/rx927zGUVQzocJ223cQOqoMTev8lpihVVIobv2tZg3GlScYvr//Aw)

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>61</s> 58 bytes (using `Data.Char.toLower`)

- Saved three bytes thanks to [nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34531/nimi).

```hs
import Data.Char
(all=<<(==).head).(toLower.head<$>).words
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDfasMgGMXvfYpDKExplgcodWNbFygUdrHedb2Q1TQyo0ENYdB3z9SUUvbhhef4@/7ZCv8jtZ4m1fXWBWxEENVbKxxpOBVa8/Wacs6qVooTq2iwOztKl@V68cSq0bqTn8JvL7GXPoCDfganzLnEq7WaERKi7bFa4ZCA41VzHAiuQYtap6oejbaDU75F42yH2gnzLYsSezdIVt7x@1Z5xGNsgMBeDMGenegiWgvtJcvokRDf2vEh9c6zPT5hnu3qU2X6EnYILI4T71guUXyZlBvRIskEgjbpld363yLxeOZ3aCw2uzR7vfA@a1bk7LGVTs7uBbkqOM9JsUiy5an43@YCG2LaqLxMMoL1y3b3vikI6YQyabvtByibFUc/hLglKgxGKyN9vHWix7zyAvn7pz8)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 5 bytes

```
#€¬uË
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9W@V/5UdOaQ2tKD3f/1/kfreSWk1@eWlSskJaTX1qUWZyhkFaUn6vgVpSYl5yqpKMUkpFZrABEefklCokKIYmlJfnpRYm5SrEA)

```
#     // split on spaces
 €¬   // get the first letter of each word
   uË // check if they're the same (uppercase) letter
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5 (`-p`), 20 bytes

```
$_=!/^(.).* (?!\1)/i
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##DcKxCoAgEADQva@4oEGDjIbGaOsLGqOQsBTMk9Po77t6vGjI98zVNpTtKpRUNYixXDrZOubJ42MoweHxJpcsHIQXTKTDborZugT/gBk0zPrOeJK@XozZYUjcRP8B)

following comments in case bad punctuation (31 bytes)

```
$_=!/^\W*+(.).*(?=\b\w)(?!\1)/i
```

[31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZRPy4mXEtbQ09TT0vD3jYmKaZcU8NeMcZQUz/z/3@3nPzy1KJihbSc/NKizOIMhbSi/FwFt6LEvORUrpCMzGIFIMrLL1FIVAhJLC3JTy9KzOVSgOnSwabtX35BSWZ@XvF/3YIcAA)

otherwise there's another approach, also with 31 bytes:

```
$h{ord()%32}++for/\w+/g;$_=2>%h
```

[31 bytes other](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9n1upmmH9XyWjOr8oRUNT1dioVls7Lb9IP6ZcWz/dWiXe1shONeP/f7ec/PLUomKFtJz80qLM4gyFtKL8XAW3osS85FSukIzMYgUgyssvUUhUCEksLclPL0rM5VKA6dLBpu1ffkFJZn5e8X/dghwA)

Comment: what about punctuations? what about spaces or punctuations at the strart of string?

Comment: this answer works for the given test cases, could be improved depending the requirements could be `$_=!/^\W*+(.).*(?=\b\w)(?!\1)/i`

Comment: but reading carefuly the question and the given solution, spaces at beginning can't occur because the spaces are used by the shell to split the arguments. The program checks only that all arguments start with the same character

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ḷṇ₁hᵛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WU9B51rFBKS8wpBrJrH@7qrH24dcL/hzu2P9zZ/qipMePh1tn//0crueXkl6cWFSuk5eSXFmUWZyikFeXnKrgVJeYlpyrpKIVkZBYrAFFefolCokJIYmlJfnpRYq5SLAA)

```
         The input
ḷ        lowercased
 ṇ₁      and split on spaces
   hᵛ    is a list of elements which all start with the same thing.
```

Comment: I just now noticed that this has to be able to handle punctuation, but without any punctuated test cases I can't tell if this does or doesn't still work...

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 54 bytes

```javascript
s=>!s.match(/\b\w+/g).some(p=s=>p-(p=Buffer(s)[0]&31))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jco9EsIgEEDh3lNgCgfGCdGxxsIiHsJYIC75GWCZ3cQcHzOewOoV75vsx7KjMc91wjcUbwqb6551tLMbZNO9uvXY9EozRpDZbDPXW2@L90CS1eP0PFzOShWHiTGADthLL6s24ArEwgdcaORBeMIoWrLJQaXU7i9@J4AfL18)

Or [**47 bytes**](https://tio.run/##jcoxDsIwDEDRnVOEDigZGoGYw8BQDoGQGgUbgtw4sls4fqg4AdOXvt4rvqMmyXXuC9@hYWgaTlv1WinPoxm98gS2hvXWfu15QQSx6q772@54cK4lLsoEnvhh0XYD8QdEDRIvkvVpUHgyg8SSoHNu8xe/CMCPty8) if each word (but the first) is guaranteed to be preceded by a space.

Comment: or in [one regex](https://tio.run/##jcpBDoIwEADAu68onHZNKPEB4A2ewIWYNHULNaVLdkGfXxNf4Jzn5d5OvcT9aDI/qYSuaNdXajd3@BXaB1i013mCezXfsI1YPGflRDbxAgHqIfGHRE1IfErU1QThzQzisqca8fJXH4Xo18sX) or with a space instead of `\W`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, using `test` saves another byte.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul You should probably post is separately.

Comment: already posted the perl version, i don't master as well javascript, i'm happy to give you a hint

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-¡`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 bytes

```
¸mÎro
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LaE=&code=uG3Ocm8=&input=IkZsb3dlcnMgZmxvdXJpc2ggZnJvbSBGcmFuY2Ui)

```
¸mÎro     :Implicit input of string
¸         :Split on spaces
 m        :Map
  Î       :  Get first character
   r      :Reduce by
    o     :  Keeping the characters that appear in both, case-insensitive
          :Implicit output as boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 41 bytes

```cs
n=>n.Split().GroupBy(c=>c[0]|32).Single()
```

Throws an exception if false, nothing if true.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBS8QwFITPza947GUTxCJ6rC0ouCJ4cgse1MMjm2wD2Zfy8qIs6m@vpQVhGBi@mbH50uYw3VkJiW6zcKBj59uJ2o7q/RiDaFM/cirj/VnbtrNvVx8/N9em3s/F6LSZGuUTO7SD/kSGQGOR2eGJ6heHhz490GG@WK@277Q1RlXC529VVa8cxOllcrGBtoONafyaTbPA50BOCxdnGlX9WhQ7/A8X5jHmFU67mL4cZ/AxFQ55AM/pBDtGsk71Q8gwi5IAQo9F0pHx9Ac)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{[eq] m:g/<<./}o&lc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJBCoMwEAXQfU7xF8W0UHTXRbVbT@CuFBkko0LitBOliHj26ON9nfpHCisyxittb/f7IDz7oqryYpfMd6k0kVbw9dLewKLG1l7@TiPYy6JjHMAqAbXS1Dl7N7YZxojzJDMIDS2z9ErBlukA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, (36 bytes)

```
s->!s.matches("(?i)(.).* (?!\\1).*")
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##jU/LasNADLz7KxSf1oUs9Ow2ueVWKCS3pgd1vbbl7sOstCml5NvdJTWlxwoxEpphGE14wW2cbZi694X8HJPAVG46Cznd52CEYtDPyXZkUGxbVXN@c2TAOGSGJ6QAX1UFpVaCBaWMS6QOfKEVHCVRGF5eAdPA0BQ9rHX8ZLFexyx6LhpxRd1rsSwK6oOLHzYx9C7mRDxCn6KHQ8JgbF1smvZ/PqeRGEqHKIBwwixxSOj/WFxveIM1/e/DDz/hd9A/LrzdbVh7FDNaVrXaU6N0o@9A7Tfn833Z6mZpr8s3)

Comment: I think the input is allowed to start with a space, and this [doesn't work for input like that](https://tio.run/##PU7LbsIwELznK5acbCQscU6BG7dKlTiWHlzHhk39iLxrUIX49mClUecwu9oZzeygb3qTRhuH/mfCMKbMMNSbKoxeuRINY4rqI9sejWbbNc1Yvj0aMF4TwbvGCI@mgYpFINZcxy1hD6HKAk6cMV4@v0DnC4Gsflhw@iW2QaXCaqwe9tXtFFtiAS0cfbrbTOB8KhnpCi6nAMeso7FtzZHdHPSceaal@//dt7/qPbjdRJv9ilTQbK6WRCsOKIWSag3isDqft3Vr5dQ9pxc).

Comment: indeed it's not a test case, but this can be [handled](https://tio.run/##PU67bsMwDNz9FYwnKUAEdHZrb9kKFMjYdFBlKaGjhyFSKYoi3@4KrtEbjgTvcMdJ3/UhzTZO423BMKfMMNWbKoxeuRINY4rqLdsRjWbbNc1cPj0aMF4TwavGCD9NAxWbQKy5jnvCEUKVBZw4Y7y8f4DOFwJZ/bDh9E1sg0qF1Vw97KvbKbbEAlo4@vRlM4HzqWSkK7icAhyzjsa2NUd2a9Bj5ZW27v93n/@qe3AvCx36Hamg2VwtiVYMPeylGFAKJdUexLA7n5/q1sqleyy/) adding `(?> *)`, using atomic group to match space at beginning and to pevent bactracking. just ` *` doesn't work because after failing matches will backtrack ` *` to match empty string

Comment: however reading the question again spaces can occur at the beginning beause in the example the usage is to pass the words as argument and spaces are shell argument delimiter